# Using Interlocked.CompareExchange to increment a counter until a value

Tags: c#, locking, task-parallel-library, task, atomic

I need to increment a counter until it reaches a particular number. I can use two parallel task to increment the number. Instead of using a lock to check if the number has not reach the maximum allowed value and then incrementing, I thought using [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx).CompareExchange in the following manner:

```
public class CompareExchangeStrategy
{
  private int _counter = 0;
   private int _max;

public CompareExchangeStrategy(int max)
{
    _max = max;
}

public void Increment()
{
    Task task1 = new Task(new Action(DoWork));
    Task task2 = new Task(new Action(DoWork));
    task1.Start();
    task2.Start();
    Task[] tasks = new Task[2] { task1, task2 };
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

}

private void DoWork()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int initial = _counter;
        if (initial >= _max)
        {
            break;
        }
        int computed = initial + 1;
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _counter, computed, initial);
    }
}

 }
```

This code is taking more to execute (for _max= 1,000,000) than the lock approach:

```
public class LockStrategy
{
    private int _counter = 0;
    private int _max;

    public LockStrategy(int max)
    {
        _max = max;
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        Task task1 = new Task(new Action(DoWork));
        Task task2 = new Task(new Action(DoWork));
        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();
        Task[] tasks = new Task[2] { task1, task2 };
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        while (true)
            {
                lock (_lockObject)
                {
                    if (_counter < _max)
                    {
                        _counter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
    }

   }
```

There might be a problem with the way I am using Interlocked.CompareExchange but I have not been able to figure out. Is there a better way to perform the above logic without using lock (aka Interlocked methods)?

---

**Update**

I was able to come with a version which performs as good as the lock version (for iterations = 1,000,000 and better for > 1,000,000 iterations).

```
    SpinWait spinwait = new SpinWait();
    int lock =0;
                while(true)
                {

                    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lock, 1, 0) != 1)
                    {

                        if (_counter < _max)
                        {
                            _counter++;
                            Interlocked.Exchange(ref lock, 0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Interlocked.Exchange(ref lock, 0);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        spinwait.SpinOnce();
                    }
                }
```

The difference is made by the spin. If the task is unable to increment the variable on first go it spins providing an opportunity for task 2 to progress further instead of performing a busy spin wait.

I suspect lock pretty much does the same, it could employ a strategy to spin and allow the thread currently owning the lock to execute.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you are actually doing a lot more work in the `Interlocked` version - by which I mean more iterations. This is because ***a lot*** of the time the `CompareExchange` *isn't doing anything*, because the value was changed by the other thread. You can see this by adding a total to each loop:

```
    int total = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int initial = Thread.VolatileRead(ref _counter);
        if (initial >= _max)
        {
            break;
        }
        int computed = initial + 1;
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _counter, computed, initial);
        total++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(total);
```

(note I also added a `VolatileRead` to ensure `_counter` isn't held in a register)

I get **much** more than iterations (via `total`) that you might expect here. The point is that when using `Interlocked` in this way, you need to add a strategy for what happens if the value changed, i.e. a retry strategy.

For example, a crude retry strategy might be:

```
    while (true)
    {
        int initial = Thread.VolatileRead(ref _counter);
        if (initial >= _max)
        {
            break;
        }
        int computed = initial + 1;
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _counter, computed, initial)
                          != initial) continue;
        total++;
    }
```

which is to say: keep retrying until you make it work - any "doing" code would only happen *after* that check (where the `total++` line is currently). This, however, makes the code more expensive.

If `lock` is cheaper: use `lock`. There's nothing wrong with `lock`, and indeed it is very optimized internally. Lock-free is not automatically the same as "fastest" or indeed "simplest".

Comment: @Ngm define "better" ;p By all accounts, it sounds like your `LockStrategy` already meets that requirement...

Comment: Agree with the reasoning and the approach. But is there a way to make this code lock free (using atomic operations) and make it faster than lock? By "better" I mean better performing than the lock version :-)

Comment: @Ngm locks are insanely cheap when they are not contested. How congested and contested do you expect this to be in your real code?

Comment: @Ngm in particular, this test is **catastrophic** for `Interlocked`: there is no "real work" happening at any time, so at all points in the test the code each thread is mutating the value of `_counter`. This is actually the pathological worst-edge-case for showing `CompareExchangeStrategy`. For this code to be *even remotely fair* to `CompareExchangeStrategy`, there should be some other non-trivial work... IMO.

Comment: This was a basic test as part of bigger scope. the real code will not have the same logic, but yes it could have contention among threads.

Comment: @Ngm I assume your actual code does something more than increment numbers? so in real code there will be less collisions? The point I'm making is: the structure of this test forces *virtually every increment* to be a collision; that is unlikely in real code.

Comment: @Ngm and again, to emphasize: there is no automatic guarantee that `Interlocked` is faster than `lock`.

Comment: Well actually I was trying out this exercise from LMAX Disruptor paper (Google: lmax disruptor pdf (first link). Refer table 1. I agree with your analysis, but there must be a better way to do it? Again my interpretation and the implementation of test might be wrong.

Comment: @Ngm that depends an awful lot on what they are doing inside the lock, and what lock implementation they are using. That 224,000 number looks unlikely and rather suspicious, to be honest; either a bad test or a bad lock implementation. Note that they are using a very different framework etc. But: I would want to see their working for that 224,000 because it sounds like someone is comparing apples and house-bricks.

Comment: The paper say the test performs an increment of a 64 bit counter for 500 million times, one of the approach: Two threads using Compare And Swap. 224,000 might be reasonable for 500 million iterations?

Comment: @Ngm not compared to the other numbers, IMO.

Comment: I was curious about the results in the LMAX paper.  Again, their test is artificial as no work occurs between the synchronized operation.  All of my results are cycles per increment.

Single Thread - 1 cyc / inc
Single Thread w/ lock - 90 cyc / inc
Two threads w/ lock   - 730 cyc / inc
Single Thread w/ CAS  - 38 cyc / inc
Two threads w/ CAS    - 250 cyc / inc
Single thread volatile - 6 cyc / inc

An interesting side note is that adding -O3 had almost no effect on results.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to achieve almost the same performance as lockstrategy using the following code:

```
public class CompareExchangeStrategy {
        volatile private int _counter = 0;
        private int _max;

        public CompareExchangeStrategy(int max) {
            _max = max;
        }

        public void Increment() {
            Task task1 = new Task(new Action(DoWork));
            Task task2 = new Task(new Action(DoWork));
            task1.Start();
            task2.Start();
            Task[] tasks = new Task[2] { task1, task2 };
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        }

        private void DoWork() {
            while(true) {
                if(Interlocked.Add(ref _counter, 1) >= _max)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The check for > _max is not atomic? all though the add operation is atomic. So you could end up with a 1,000,001?

Comment: minor note; `Interlocked.Increment` is probably more idiomatic than `Interlocked.Add(..., 1)`; but indeed, this doesn't address the "one too many" issue (or even a few too many, if using > 2 threads).

Comment: Yes, it ends up with 1000001.  I just wanted to speed up the interlocked approach as much as possible.  I did not find a way to make it work faster.

Comment: (changing the `>` for `>=` doesn't remove the thread-race condition, btw; it may not exhibit it every time, but it is possible to end up with the 1,000,001 even with the `>=`)

Comment: yes, i looked at the original code and changed mine according to it.  It usually ends up with 1000001 because two tasks working and there is no the condition before changing the value.