# C# get max value from multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# server application which listens to TCP clients. Each client creates a new thread on server, and it will pass an integer value to server every 10ms.

Now I need to get the biggest integer from all clients and broadcast it continuesly, so I think the question is how I can get all values from different threads and compare them together?

Comment: The thread passes a value into your comparison method - `ShowMaxValue(maxValue)` which then compares it to it's own total - `if (maxValue > total) { total = maxValue; }`

Comment: @Ben - You'd need some form of locking around that to make it work - otherwise it's a race condition waiting to happen.

Comment: @Enigmativity among other possible things. But until the OP posts what they have currently, there's any number of things we can offer as a solution. Because we don't know what their code is, we really can't offer a working solution.

Comment: Do you mean biggest within one cycle of everyone sending a value, or is this a running biggest value across all senders ever?

Comment: Thank you all for reply, I want a running biggest value across all senders ever. I don't have any codes yet, I need to know how then I can start my code...  I just think that is it possible that each thread will have their own variable a[i] to store the value, and I can create another thread to loop through to get max, like int maxium = max(a)

Answer (score 4):

Two good options and one OK option:

1. Use a [`ConcurrentQueue<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) into which each thread inserts values, have a single reader thread that reads values out and updates the maximum.
2. Use a volatile int shared across the threads and use [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange) to update it atomically in a retry loop (e.g. similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15495942/224370)).
3. Use a [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) around the max calculation and update a [volatile int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx).

Comment: I've come up a simple solution, please help to update... I don't know how to use Interlock at all... <br/>

Answer (score 0):

I've come up a simple solution

//Define a static class first...

```
public static class IntHolder
{
    public static int Value;
}
```

in thread update the Value of the static class, and other threads compare it, only if the value is bigger then update it. In this way, all threads can visit same memory address

```
if (IntHolder.Value < Int32.Parse(dataFromClient))
{
  IntHolder.Value = Int32.Parse(dataFromClient);
}
```

Please correct me if I wrong... Or any better solution, I know it will have race condition but I'm not sure how to use lock...

Thanks!